# backward selection but regression coefficients not significative?

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance

I'm running a logistic regression with backard selection method. I get coefficients with p-values>.10. Here's an example:

```
    DF   Estimate   Error   Chi-Square  Pr > ChiSq  Estimate    Exp(Est)
Intercept   1   -30,32       11,48       6,97        0,01            -     
v1  1    0,001       0,00        9,70        0,00        0,10        1,00   
v2  1   -0,001       0,00        2,84        0,09       -0,07        1,00   
v3  1    0,000       0,00        0,12        0,73        0,01        1,00   
v4  1   -0,000       0,00        0,11        0,74       -0,01        1,00   
v5  1   -0,000       0,00        0,74        0,39       -0,03        1,00   
v6  1    0,000       0,00        0,58        0,45        0,02        1,00   
v7  1   -0,005       0,00        3,98        0,05       -0,07        1,00   
v8  1    0,002       0,01        0,04        0,84        0,01        1,00   
v9  1   -0,016       0,05        0,09        0,76       -0,02        0,98   
v10 1    0,014       0,03        0,29        0,59        0,03        1,01   
v11 1    0,102       0,03        14,77       0,00        0,09        1,11   
v12 1    0,009       0,01        1,27        0,26        0,05        1,01   
v13 1   -0,017       0,01        2,39        0,12       -0,05        0,98   
v14 1   -0,005       0,01        0,48        0,49       -0,03        1,00
```

My question is, if the algorithm selects best variables, how is it be possible that keeps the variables that have p-values greater than 0.1? I know that the effect is reflected in the value of the coefficient but the pvalue shows the probability that having that value in that coefficient is only a coincidence, and the coefficient is 0 (considering all the other variables). So why is still keeping those?

Comment: How were you doing the backwards elimination? What functions, what test statistic or selection method, AIC etc? How did you generate the table of "results" shown? These are important details.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this in R? If so R defaults the p-val to something, I am not quite sure but you can look it up in the help. Thus you can change what "significance" level you want to discard at. Backwards selection in my experience is usually not a good approach. Unless you are restricted to using backwards selection I would suggest using a different method of model selection.

Comment: Depends what you by "in R"? The default `step()` function doesn't explicitly use the $p$ value at all. Instead it uses AIC to do selection. That may well explain what the OP is seeing, as may other things. We need more details to answer this.